# AWS Lambda using a Container Image throwing a no space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, containers

I am trying to figure out if there is a config issue that needs resolving or if I really somehow ended up using all 10GB (though that seems unlikely as the image is 849MB) but I am getting a no space left on device error when running my lambda with containers. Any one know why that might be? (do I need to dump things to a tmp folder? I am trying to run a tensor flow project in this particular lambda, so that may be a thing I need to investigate?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-reqs)

> The container image must be able to run on a read-only file system. Your function code can access a writable /tmp directory with 512 MB of storage.

So if you're attempting to write a file in the "current" directory (normally `/var/task`), it won't work.

There are several ways that you can work around this:

1. If your file fits in 512 MB and then gets uploaded somewhere, write it to `/tmp`.
2. Use in-memory data structures (you don't mention your language, but, for example, `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` in Python, or `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` in Java). The "10 GB" that you mention in your question is memory (RAM), not disk.
3. If you need to write to disk, and need more than 512 MB, [mount an EFS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-efs.html).

Comment: yeah I figured out real quick that the 512 limit still exists even for containerized lambdas. Found a workaround, basically pre-loaded the resource into the container. EFS sounds like a great solution, may have to dig into that deeper, but I may be ultimately going a different route for this app...

Comment: You can now configure lambdas so you can save up to 10GB in `/tmp`. See [docs here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/).